# Cannot add a UIDatePicker to UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

I want to add a UIDatePicker to a UIActionSheet, the code is below:

```
UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"DEMO" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancle" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];


 actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ratings" 
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];   
[actionSheet sendSubviewToBack:pickerView];  

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];

CGRect pickerRect = pickerView.bounds;
pickerRect.origin.y = -100;
pickerView.bounds = pickerRect;

[pickerView release];
[actionSheet release];
```

The question is why this code cannot work in iPad mode while it is ok in iphone mode

Comment: did you get answer or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [EAActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/EckyZero/EAActionSheetPickerDemo). It handles that for you.